# Значеннєва різниця між "через те що" і "тому що" як переклад "because"

Tags: вибір-слова, сполучники

Чи є значеннєва різниця між *через те що* і *тому що*? Тут мене вони цікавлять як переклад *because*.

> **Because** the Schur complement is nonsingular, we can now recursively find an
>   LU decomposition for it.
>
> **Через те що**/**Тому що** доповнення Шура невироджене, LU-розклад для нього можна знайти
>   рекурсивно.

[А-у-а словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки) 2010](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%89%D0%BE&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) подає

> **because** тому́ що; че́рез те що; оскі́льки; бо; позая́к ■

Comment: Щодо самого питання ще подумаю, але мені тут найкраще звучить "позаяк".

Comment: @P.Vowk Витяг з "Як ми говоримо": *Вiзьмiмо, примiром, одiозне колись слово позаяк (нiби синонiм до загальновживаних бо, через те що, тому що), без якого рiдко хто обходився серед дореволюцiйних українських публiцистiв та промовцiв; чи є це штучне, непотрiбне слово в грiнченкiвському словнику? Нi, нема, як не знайдете там i багатьох iнших подiбних див, що могли проскочити, але не прижилися в живiй мовi народу.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107691/discussion-on-question-by-yola---------).

Comment: В аналогічних ситуаціях я перекладаю "because" як "оскільки". 
("Оскільки доповнення Шура невироджене ...")

Обидва вирази "через те що" і "тому що" є зміст використовувати тільки коли необхідно приєднати підрядне речення. 

Вираз "через те що" має легке негативне емоційне забарвлення.
Вираз "тому що" - більш емоційно нейтральний.
Емоційно позитивний преклад "because of" - "завдяки"

Comment: @Volodymyr коли ми перекладали [CLRS](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B2), то наш мовний редактор пояснював, що *оскільки* це полонізм і тому ви в цій книзі його не знайдете, тому тут я про нього й не запитував. Щодо негативного, то якби знайти якесь джерело на підтвердження цього, то було б дуже добре.

Comment: @Yola Не варто вживати складні конструкції там де можна обійтись одним словом. "Оскільки" ідеально підходить для згаданої ситуації. Це слово - не полонізм, принаймні в польській в аналогічних ситуаціях вживається "ponieważ". (порівняйте також з російським "поскольку").

Answer (score 3):

Не певен, чи є якесь правило стосовно цього, але

---

**(Через те\Завдяки тому) що (причина), (наслідок)**

**(Оскільки\Позаяк\Так як) (причина), (наслідок)**

Пояснює спочатку *причину*, а потім *наслідок* у одному реченні.

---

**(наслідок), (тому що\бо) (причина)**

Пояснює спершу *наслідок*, а потім *причину* у одному реченні.

**- (наслідок)?**

**- (Тому що\Бо) (причина)**

Також може пояснювати причину у окремому реченні.

---

Отже, у запропонованих у питанні прикладах доцільно буде використати **через те що**.

Про пунктуацію та інший правопис не скажу.

Comment: Я згоден, що частіше кажуть «_<наслідок>_, тому що _<причина>_» і «через те що _<причина>_, _<наслідок>_» (аніж «_<наслідок>_, через те що _<причина>_» і тим паче «тому що _<причина>_, _<наслідок>_»). Але ж і в зворотному порядку теж кажуть. Тому я не певен на 100%, що справа тут лише в порядку підречень (можливо, якась конотаційна різниця теж є), але, звісно, із тим, що порядок підречень — важливий фактор, я згоден.

Comment: Мені здається, що можна перекручувати речення як завгодно, використовуючи вставні речення чи інші конструкції. Аби воно мало сенс. «тому що, <причина>, <наслідок>» = _тому що, як я вже казав раніше, це не важливо_.

Answer (score -1):

**через те що** і **тому що**

**тому що** *(because)* пояснює причинно-наслідковий зв'язок;

**через те що** *(because of)* називає фактично встановлений зв'язок, з якої саме конкретної причини або обставини відбулись наслідки

Наприклад,

*"ВЕРХОВНА РАДА ВИЗНАЛА КАРАНТИН ЧЕРЕЗ КОРОНАВІРУС ФОРС-МАЖОРНОЮ ОБСТАВИНОЮ"*

**Через те, що** Верховна Рада визнала Карантин форс-мажорною обставиною, міжнародні поставки по укладеним Договорам можуть бути відтерміновані на час дії карантинних заходів.

Міжнародні поставки по укладеним Договорам були зірвані **тому, що** Верховна Рада визнала Карантин форс-мажорною обставиною.

Comment: Про окреме «через» загалом зрозуміло — це прийменник, а не сполучник. А чим «через те що» відрізняється від «тому що»?

Comment: "Тому, що" відповідає на питання "Чому?"

Comment: "Через те, що" відповідає на питання "Чому саме?" / "З якої причинини?"

Comment: Тобмо «через те, що» — це більш точне вказання причини ніж «тому, що», — я правильно зрозумів?

Comment: саме так, внірно зрозуміли

Comment: Ваш приклад не відповідає питанню. Порівняти потрібно саме синонімічні вирази "через те що" і "тому що".

Comment: Згодний. Навів доречний приклад і з'ясувалося, що конструкцію «тому що» можна використати лише в підрядному складі речення, на відміну від «через те що», яке можна вжити і на початку речення.

Comment: @RomanMikhol, так, мені теж здається, що «через те що» може бути як на початку, так і в середині речення, а «тому що» вживають частіше всередині речення. Але на практиці його вживають і на початку, наприклад: «Тому, що нас багато, що нас більшість, ніхто, здається, не звертає уваги на втрати» (Уляна Кравченко, «Спогади учительки», 1887), «Тому, що краєва Рада шкільна скорше може оцїнити, котрі бурси відповідають свому заданю, а через те заслугують і на запомогу, то Видїл краєвий спитав єї о гадку про ті бурси, що внесли просьби» («Запомога для бурс», з журналу «Народна Часопись», 1892).

Answer (score -2):

Це залежить від того, хто пише — песиміст або оптиміст.

### Приклад

**Річки забруднюються через те, що в них викидають сміття** (між рядків: безнадійне відношення, на це ніяк неможна вплинути. Так було, є і буде)
другий приклад:

**Річки забрудюються тому що в них викидають сміття** (між рядків: оптимістичне ставлення, з цим треба боротись і можна досягнути успіхів. Так було, є, але треба з цим щось робити)

З іншого погляду, може висловлювати тривалість ставлення при використанні «через те що», та завершеність дії при використанні «тому що».

### Приклад

**Це стається** (або сталось) **через те що ти ніколи мене не слухаєш.** (безнадійне ставлення: песимістичне. Тривалість: воно завжди так буде).

**Це сталось тому що ти мене не послухав** (оптимістично: сподівання, що наступний раз послухає пораду. Засудження. Тривалість: це сталось в данному випадку, в інший раз буде інший випадок)

### Висновок:

***Це замінні сполуки, які використовує автор, щоб забарвити зміст певним відтінком та передати відношення до події, того, що сталось.***

Comment: Чесно кажучи, не відчуваю особливого песимізму/оптимізму в першому прикладі (але не кажу, що цього немає, просто я особисто не бачу). Щодо другого прикладу, то, по-моєму, тривалість/завершеність визначаєтсься радше формами дієслів («стається»/«сталось» і «ніколи не слухаєш»/«не послухав»), аніж вибором між «через те що» і «тому що».

Comment: До речі, у Вас у прикладах не вистачає ком. Але коми в таких реченнях можна ставити по-різному («А, тому що Б» і «А тому, що Б»; «А, через те що Б» і «А через те, що Б» — залежно від інтонації, яку хочете передати), тому я не наважився редагувати, щоб не спотворити думку.

Comment: Все, що у вас написано - чистий суб'єктивізм.

Comment: Я теж вважаю, що вирази "через те що" → "тому що" →  "завдяки тому що" відрізняються емоційним забарвленням, але я не зміг так сходу знайти підтвердження цього мого відчуття.

Comment: @Volodymyr річ у тім, що в запитані не йдеться про завдяки. *Завдяки* і *через те що* дійсно мають різне емоційне забарвлення. Хоча може й *тому що* має емоційну відмінність від *через те що*.